# TCP socket handling for multiplayer game on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a multiplayer game where my server uses nodejs and TCPSocket (net.createServer) to communicate with a client.

I have thousands of clients connecting to the server and many people are complaining that they are constantly being disconnected from the server.

Here is how my server handles the connections now:

**Init:**

```
var net = require("net"); 
server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(15000);
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    socket.myBuffer = "";
    socket.msgsQue = [];

    socket.on("data", onData); 
    socket.on("error", onError);            
    socket.on("end", onClientDisconnect);
    socket.on("timeout", onClientDisconnect); 
});  
server.listen(port);
```

**Sending to client:**

```
var stringData = JSON.stringify({name:event, message:data});
if (!this.socket.msgsQue || typeof this.socket.msgsQue == "undefined") 
        this.socket.msgsQue = [];

this.socket.msgsQue.unshift(stringData);
var i = this.socket.msgsQue.length;
while(i--) {
    if (this.socket.writable) {
        var elem = this.socket.msgsQue[i];
        this.socket.write(elem+"\0");
        this.socket.msgsQue.splice(i, 1);
     } else {
         //Unable to write at index "i"
         break;//will send the rest on the next attempt
     }
}
```

**When disconnected**

```
var onClientDisconnect = function() {
    this.myBuffer = "";
    delete this.myBuffer;
    this.msgsQue = [];
    delete this.msgsQue;
    this.destroy();
}
```

**Receiving from client**

```
    var onData = function(data) {
        if (!data || !data.toString()) return;
        var raw = data.toString();
        this.myBuffer += raw;
        var d_index = this.myBuffer.indexOf('\0'); // Find the delimiter

         // While loop to keep going until no delimiter can be found
        var string;
        while (d_index > -1) {
            // Create string up until the delimiter                 
            string = this.myBuffer.substring(0,d_index);
            // Cuts off the processed chunk          
            this.myBuffer = this.myBuffer.substring(d_index+1); 
            onMessage(string, this);//handle
            // Find the new delimiter
            d_index = this.myBuffer.indexOf('\0'); 
        } 
    }
```

A problem I notice is that `msgsQue` becomes huge because the socket is not writable, but disconnect handler is not fired (or hired later..)

**Can you give me some advises on how to optimize this ?**

I noticed that sometimes I get disconnected, but I can ping the server, so it is definitely a server-related problem. Can it be because of high load on the server itself?

*(I do not want to use socket.io because the last year I had many problems with it like memory leaking, freezing the server app, no support, etc..)*

Comment: cannot give any advice, but yes, it could be related to high load average, which may cause, for example, load balancers to come in, and it may interfere.